# A question about dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

Consider the portion of code below (please do not care about deleting the `firstArray` and `secondArray`):

```
int *firstArray = new int[10];
int *secondArray = new int[20];

firstArray = secondArray;
```

I have three questions here:

1. Is the expression `firstArray = secondArray;` safe even though they have two different sizes?

   ps: It seems the compiler (code::blocks) does not complain.
2. Now that `firstArray` and `secondArray` have the same address, what happens if I delete one of the arrays, is the other one deleted too?
3. Why, when I delete the second one, the application crashes.

Comment: You're just overwriting one pointer with another, which will be leaking memory in consequence, because you don't have any chance to call `delete` for it anymore.

Comment: Deleting the same pointer twice leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: `firstArray` and `secondArray` have the same size.  They are both pointers, both have type `int*`, and both have size `sizeof(int*)`.  They hold a memory address, and when you assign one to the other, both point to the same memory address.

Comment: `firstArray = secondArray;` causes a memory leak since you no longer have a pointer to the memory allocated in the `int *firstArray = new int[10];` so you can't free that allocation.

Comment: It is my suspicion that before asking about dynamic memory allocation, you should further study what a pointer is.  Your question seems to imply that you are confusing _a pointer_ with _the object that is pointed to_.  Your code is dealing with four objects.  Two objects are pointers and two objects are arrays that came from `new`, and therefore should eventually be `delete`d.

Comment: I write my home address on a piece of paper. Then you write your home address on another piece of paper. Then I erase my address from my paper and write yours down instead. Even though your house is bigger than mine I can still write your address on my paper. And, my house still exists, but we no longer have the address written down to find it!

Comment: 1. yes 2. The pointer to the array pointed to by `firstArray` is gone after the assignment without any way of recovering it; both `firstArray` and `secondArray` point to the same memory after the assignment. Those are not 2 arrays. 3. Calling `delete[]` on the same array multiple times is undefined behaviour; The program noticing that the memory you try to free does not belong to the program anymore indicates an issue with the program logic; crashing the program in order to prevent more errors resulting from a incorrect assertion is the likely result.

Comment: Use smart pointers.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Better: Use `std::array`. There is nothing there needing dynamic memory. And if it where then `std::vector` would cover it.

Comment: For @Remy Lebeau, thanks for indenting my question, I am new, I will try to do better next time

Comment: For πάντα ῥεῖ, Drew Dormann, Mark Ransom, drescherjm,  Kevin, Jesper Juhl, fabian and Goswin von Brederlow, thank you very much for your fast comments, I hope you continue with me below

Comment: When the memory is leaked, Does the operating system will take care of it, or it will be hold until computer reboot?

Comment: @Ninja the OS will reclaim unfreed memory when the allocating process terminates. Until then, leaked memory just hangs around taking up resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's talk about what you're doing here.

1. Is it safe? Yes. But it's a mistake because you have orphaned the data that secondArray used to point to. They now point to the same space in memory.

Imagine that firstArray holds the memory address 0x1000 and secondArray holds address 0x2000. After this assignment, they both hold 0x1000, and 0x2000 is orphaned.

2. If you delete [] firstArray, then continuing to reference 0x1000 by either pointer can lead you into trouble. You're going to step all over who knows what.
3. You've now engaged in undefined behavior, and crashes are common when you engage in undefined behavior.

Now, here's some opinion. It's important to understand the underlying memory systems, but once you do, start using various smarter containers. You can use std::array instead, for instance, and then you don't have to deal with memory allocation at all. This eliminates huge classes of bugs.

Comment: `firstArray` getting overwritten, and orphaned. Everything else is also mixed up due to this.

Comment: Thank you @Joseph Larson, amazing explanation.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer is just a number that corresponds to some memory location.

Operator `new T[N]` allocates a block of memory (of size `N * sizeof(T)`) and gives you the address of the first element.

Operator `delete[] (T*)` uses the value you pass to it to recall what memory was allocated and reclaims it for further allocations.

The expression `firstArray = secondArray;` sets the value of `firstArray` to the value of `secondArray` (not unlike if they were just integers). From here on out both pointers point to the same memory (and the original value of `firstArray` is forgotten).

When you subsequently `delete[]` one of them, the memory that is pointed to by those pointers is freed (and the corresponding entry in the allocator is removed).

When you `delete[]` the other pointer, the memory was already deleted, so the program will have *undefined behavior* and might crash.

And, of course, since the original value of `firstArray` is forgotten, there is no way to delete it now - there is a memory leak.